# Mouseenter event firing twice on hover and also firing mouseleave code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fade in and fade out some icons using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` but I've noticed that my code isn't working so great. I added some console logs to my code and noticed on mouseenter my mouseleave log is also being called. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

JSFiddle of problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BndxN/1
When I hover over the menu quickly the icons appear below the button?

JS

```
/* On sharePage hover hide label and display social icons */
$sharePage.mouseenter(function(){
    $sharePageLabel.fadeOut(function(){
        $socialIconItems.each(function(i){
            $(this).delay(i*45).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
            //console.log($(this));
        });
    });
});
$sharePage.mouseleave(function() {
    $($socialIconItems.get().reverse()).each(function(i){
        $(this).delay(i*305).fadeOut();
        if(i==3){$sharePageLabel.fadeIn()}
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="sharePage">
      <h3>Pass The Party On</h3>
      <ul id="socialIcons" class="cf">
        <li><a href="" class="fb ir" data-network="facebook" data-shareurl="">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="twitter ir" data-network="twitter" data-shareurl="">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="googlePlus ir" data-network="google" data-shareurl="">Google+</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="email ir" data-network="email" data-shareurl="">Email</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a set of `});` at the end of your code.

Comment: sorry, missed them when pasting in code

Comment: Can you show the HTML? Probably an event bubbling is happening here...

Comment: Also there's an erronious }); after if(i==3){$sharePageLabel.fadeIn()}. the if is tabbed in but it has no reason to be because the line above doesn't wrap it

Comment: @popnoodles My mistake while editing. Didn't see. Restored the original one. :)

Comment: What happens if you change `$sharePage.mouseenter` to `$sharePage.unbind('mouseenter').mouseenter`?

Comment: When you enter 1, does it leave another..? Paste your HTML ;)

Comment: Just added HTML, hope this helps!

Comment: And just added a fiddle of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/BndxN/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your icon fade out isn't being triggered because it's fade in from the mouseenter event hasn't finished. Adding a timeout on the fadeout animation (for the duration of the timein) seems to fix it.

See jsfiddle.net/BndxN/26/

Edit - You might want to tweak the timeout duration a little.

Comment: great! would this code also work for tablet or would I have to add in a click event?

Comment: It would need to be click...touch screen devices don't lend themselves well to hovering :)